# A question about differentiability

Tags: calculus

Does there exist a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ so that $f$ is differentiable exactly at one point?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Idea: choose a function which is continuous but nowhere differentiable. Then multiply it with $x^2$, say.

Comment: Following noone's idea, you may find a concrete example such as

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 & x \in \Bbb{Q} \\ -x^2 & x \in \Bbb{R}\setminus\Bbb{Q} \end{cases}.$$

Comment: @sos440 why would this be continuous?

Comment: I missed the condition that $f$ must be continuous. Here is a correct example: $f(x) = x^2 \mathrm{blanc}(x)$, where $\mathrm{blanc}(x)$ is the *[blancmange function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blancmange_curve)*.